# python django variables from views.py to html show the code intead of the value

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to print my products from sqlite
the problem is that the result in the browser is the code itself and not the value.

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Product


def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'dict': products})
```

**index.html:**

```
<ul>
    {% for prod in dict %}
        <li>{{ prod.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**The result in the browser is:**

```
{% for prod in dict %}
{{ prod.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How are you checking your results? Are you running the server or directly opening index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this you need to check index.html by running the server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and going to the url that leads to index.html

Answer (score 0):

if the result in the browser is like the one you said, are you opening the HTML file directly? because if Django rendered the template it wouldn't show this. even if the data is wrong or there is nothing, it'll just display nothing